# How to order Nested Collections in Linq and EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, frameworks, entity

i would like to make a treelistview for my Data.

Tree should look like this

> Accounts
>   -> Providers
>     
>  -> Accounts

```
public sealed class AccountRoot    
{
    public AccountRoot()
    {
        Providers = new Collection<Hoster>();
    }

    public long AccountRootId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Hoster> Providers { get; set; } 

}

public sealed class Hoster
{
    public Hoster()
    {
        Accounts = new Collection<Account>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long HosterId { get; set; }
    public long AccountRootId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; } 
}

public sealed class Account
{
    [Key]
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    public long HosterId { get; set; }
    public Hoster Hoster { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to order my query.

should be sth like

Accounts

Providers A-Z

Accounts A-Z

what i got until now is..

```
var query = _entity.AccountRoot.Local
                   .Select(x => new AccountRoot()
                   {
                        AccountRootId = x.AccountRootId,
                        Providers = x.Providers.OrderBy(y => y.Name).ToList()
                   }).ToList();
```

What is missing is the `orderby` for the next nested collection.

Thank you for your help ! :-)

Comment: why do you select from `Local` btw ?

Comment: my entity is singleton, cause i need it for lists ... did tried it with short-lived entity but didn't work for my purpose .. thank you !

Comment: Do you need a single query to achieve the end result? or you just need to sort the data from pre populated objects (`Locale` is `ObservableCollection`) to achieve the end result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a bit different approaches depending on if you already have a result set, and want to just sort it in code, or if you want to construct `IQueryable<>` for EF which will be successfully compiled to SQL and executed with actual sorting in database.

First, assume you already have the collection in code. In this case, you have object `AccountRoot`, which contains collection of `Providers`, each of which has collection of `Accounts`. Obviously, you cannot return the same objects, as you need to reorder collection properties, so all you need is to just construct new ones. I would just sort the collections, but you could construct completely new entities, if you need:

```
var query = ...
    .Select(x => new AccountRoot
    {
        // add copy properties here
        // ....
        Providers = x.Providers
                        .Select(y =>
                        {
                            // Here we can construct completely new entity, 
                            // with copying all properties one by one,
                            // or just reorder existing collection as I do here
                            var result = y;
                            result.Accounts = y.Accounts.OrderBy(z => z.Name).ToArray();
                            return result;
                        })
                        .OrderBy(y => y.Name)
                        .ToArray()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Second case, if you need to get it directly from SQL, is a bit different, as you cannot use all that `var result = ...; ... return result` stuff in lambda - it won't compile to SQL. But idea is the same - you need to construct projection from data sets. It should be something like this:

```
var query = ...
    .Select(x => new AccountRoot
    {
        AccountRootId = x.AccountRootId,
        // Other properties to copy
        // ...
        Providers = x.Providers
                        .Select(y => new Hoster
                        {
                            HosterId = y.HosterId,
                            // Other properties to copy
                            // ...
                            Accounts = y.Accounts.OrderBy(z => z.Name).ToArray(),
                        })
                        .OrderBy(y => y.Name)
                        .ToArray()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: works the way i want it !! perfect answer ... i've choose the second one cause i need it directly :-) Thank you !!